# How can i get value by specific key by other specific key

Tags: php, arrays

I have following array:

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
      (
          [id] => pencil
          [label] => blue pencil 123
      )
  [1] => Array
      (
          [id] => eraser
          [label] => green eraser 123
      )
)
```

And I know the id (eraser) but I don't know the label (green eraser 123), how can I get label (green eraser 123) by known unique id (eraser)?

Can I do this in a loop for each element?

Comment: yes, try with loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$arr = [
    [
        'id'    => 'pencil',
        'label' => 'blue pencil 123',
    ],
    [
        'id'    => 'eraser',
        'label' => 'green eraser 123',
    ],
];

function getLabelFromId ($arr, $id) {
    foreach ($arr as $row) {
        if ($row['id'] == $id) {
            return $row['label'];
        }
    }
    return null;
}

var_dump(getLabelFromId($arr, 'pencil'));
var_dump(getLabelFromId($arr, 'eraser'));
```

Outputs:

```
string(15) "blue pencil 123"
string(16) "green eraser 123"
```

[eval.in demo](https://eval.in/892548)

Comment: Thanks for your help and response, you're awesome :)